# Passing props from parent to sibling in React

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am recreating a simple React app that I have already created in Angular. The React app has two components: one (menus.js) for a side menu and a second (content.js) that will display the content from each item in the menu when each link is clicked (just like an iframe of sorts). In the App.js I am making a REST API call to populate the state for the menus.js component. Note that both components are in the App.js as follows:

**App.js**

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import Menus from './components/menus';
import Content from './components/content';

class App extends Component {

  state = {
    menus: []
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    fetch('api address')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then((data)=> {
      this.setState({menus: data})
    })
    .catch(console.log)
  }

  render(){
  return (
    <div>
      <div><Menus menus={this.state.menus} /></div>
      <div><Content /></div>
    </div>
  );
}
}

export default App;
```

**here is the menu.js component; it takes a prop (menus) from App.js and builds the menu links with items from it:**

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Link,} from "react-router-dom";
  const Menus = ({ menus }) => {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
          <center><h1>Lessons</h1></center>
          {menus.map(menu => (
            <li key={menu.lesson}>
              <Link to={`/lesson/${menu.lesson}`}>{menu.lessonName}</Link>
            </li>
          ))}
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  };
  export default Menus;
```

**Here is what I need - how do I pass items from the same prop (from App.js) to the content component? FYI - I need this to happen each time a link in the menu in menu.js is clicked (which is why a key is used in the list** The simple idea is content will update in the content component each time a menu link in the menu component is clicked.

```
**content.js**

import React from 'react'

const Content = () => {
  return (
    <div>{menu.content}</div>
  )
};

export default Content
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `menu.js`, attach the `menu` object to the `Link`

```js
...
{menus.map(menu => (
    <li key={menu.lesson}>
        <Link to={{
          pathname: `/lesson/${menu.lesson}`,
          state: menu
        }}> {menu.lessonName} </Link> 
    </li>
))}
...
```

In your `content.js` receive the `menu` like this:

```js
import React from 'react'

const Content = () => {
  console.log(props.location.state.menu.content);
  return (
    <div>{props.location.state && props.location.state.menu.content }</div>
  )
};

export default Content
```

Read more [here](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Link)

Comment: Im getting a no-template-curly-in-string warning, but the example uses single quotes. Supposedly it is here: pathname: `/lesson/${menu.lesson}`,

Comment: yes right, the `menu` is already an object ... so try this -- <Link to={{
          pathname: `/lesson/${menu.lesson}`,
          state:  menu 
        }}> {menu.lessonName} </Link> .. i will update the answer

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description of the problem and what I can see of what you've written, it seems to me like you are trying to build an application where the menu persists, but the content changes based on menu clicks. For a simple application, this is how I would structure it differently.

```
<ParentmostComponent>
  <MenuComponent someProp={this.state.some_data} />
      <Switch>
        <Route path={"/path"} render={(props) => <Dashboard {...props} someProp={this.state.some_other_data_from_parents} />
      </Switch>
</ParentMostComponent>
```

This would allow the menu to always stay there no matter what the content is doing, and you also won't have to pass the menu prop to two components.

Answer (score 0):

Your example uses *React Router*, so this answer uses it as well.

First of all, move the `Router` up the hierarchy from `Menus` to `App` to make the router props available to all components. Then wrap your `Content` inside a `Route` to render it conditionally (i.e. if the path matches `"/lesson/:lesson"`):

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    menus: [
      {
        lesson: '61355373',
        lessonName: 'Passing props from parent to sibling in React',
        content: 'I am recreating a simple React app…'
      },
      {
        lesson: '27991366',
        lessonName: 'What is the difference between state and props in React?',
        content: 'I was watching a Pluralsight course on React…'
      }
    ]
  }

  render() {
    const { menus } = this.state

    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
          <div><Menus menus={menus}/></div>
          <Route path="/lesson/:lesson" render={({ match }) => (
            <div><Content menu={menus.find(menu => menu.lesson === match.params.lesson)}/></div>
          )}>
          </Route>
        </div>
      </Router>
    )
  }
}
```

With the help of the [`render` prop](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/render-func), you can access the router props (in this case `match.params.lesson`) before rendering your child component. We use them to pass the selected menu to `Content`. Done!

Note: The basic technique (without *React Router*, *Redux* etc.) to pass props between siblings is to [lift the state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html).